# Задача в том чтобы функция показала все числа в списке, которые больше n

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    list1= [1,2,41,634,75,8,9]
    list1 = list1.sort()
    n = int(input('Введите число: '))
    print(list1[n:])
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Метод  sort сортирует список "in place". И индекс для слайса найти чуть сложнее

```
def main():
    list1= [1,2,41,634,75,8,9]
    list1.sort()
    n = int(input('Введите число: '))
    for i,v in enumerate(list1):
      if v > n:
        break
    else:
      return
    print(list1[i+1:])
main()
```

Так сортировка не нужна

```
def main():
    list1= [1,2,41,634,75,8,9]
    n = int(input('Введите число: '))
    print([x  for x in list1 if x > n])
main()
```

Comment: здесь тогда и сортировка не нужна, если вы все равно при каждой итерации проверяете условие

Comment: может, ему упорядоченно надо

Comment: он сортировку делал, что бы потом якобы от нужного числа показать массив, но перепутал число и индекс числа

Comment: Согласен, поправил ответ